# Where does the process go after changing to state TASK_STOPPED in Linux?

Tags: process, linux-kernel

Supposed that we have a runnning process in Linux system, the state of that process will be TASK_RUNNING, after that if It receive the SIGSTOP signal , the process's state will change to TASK_STOPPED.

So I wonder if that process is still in the Running queue?, does the kernel put it to somewhere after change the state from TASK_RUNNING into TASK_STOPPED?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: TASK_STOPPED: task was stopped, either due to the job completed or due to signal. Now the next thing would for the kernel to clean up any allocations and free the data structures for the process.